# PowerShell Function to return a variable

Tags: function, variables, powershell

I'm writing a function to create a variable called `$Credentials` which I use in another function to verify if it's valid or not. By using `return $Credentials`in the function I hoped the variable would've been available after the `Function Import-Password` has ran, but this isn't the case..

I think this could be solved by using `$script:Credentials`, but I don't think it's needed if the function can output this variable.

Thank you for your help.

**Function Import-Password**

```
# Check the password file
Function Import-Password ($UserName,$PasswordFile,[switch]$SendMail) {
    try {
        if (!(Test-Path $PasswordFile)) {
            Write-Host "$env:COMPUTERNAME > Check password file: $PasswordFile > The password file can not be found`n
            - Password file :`t $PasswordFile
            - Server name   :`t $env:COMPUTERNAME" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            if ($SendMail) {
                Send-Mail "FAILED AD Authentication" "The password file can not be found" "- Password file : $PasswordFile<br>- Server name   : $env:COMPUTERNAME"
            }
            break
        }
        $Password = cat $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$Password 
        return $Credentials
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "$env:COMPUTERNAME > Check password file: $PasswordFile > The password has been hashed with another account than the account used to run this script (all 3 users/owners need to be the same)`n
        - Script account:`t $env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME
        - Password user :`t $UserName
        - Password file :`t $PasswordFile
        " -ForegroundColor Yellow
        if ($SendMail) {
            Send-Mail "FAILED AD Authentication" "The password has been hashed with another account than the account used to run this script (all 3 users/owners need to be the same)" "- Script account: $env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME<br>- Password user : $UserName<br>- Password file : $PasswordFile"
        }
        break
    } 
}
Import-Password $UserName $PasswordFile
```

Comment: Is it possible that your code ends up in the exception handler? No return value is specified there. Scoping should not play a role here.

Comment: Yes, the code sometimes ends up in the `Catch` block when the `ConvertTo-SecureString` fails. This might happen if the incorrect user is running the script.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think I misunderstood what you were asking, but I see that @KeithHill provided an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to capture the output of the function in order to use it later in your script e.g.:

```
$cred = Import-Password $UserName $PasswordFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But is there an option to have the function return the variable `$Password` also? Because I use `$Credentials` for the `Invoke-Command` later on in the script and `$Password` in another function to verify it.

Comment: The SecureString version of the password will be available as a property on the PSCredential you return.

Comment: @DarkLite1: What Keith said. However, for the sake of completeness, you can return an array with multiple elements (e.g. `return $Credentials, $password`) and capture the elements of the returned array in separate variables: `$cred, $passwd = Import-Password ...`. The last left-hand variable captures all remaining elements of the returned array if there are more elements than variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this was exactly what I was looking for. Works like a freight train! :)